# Read site source: � characters

Tags: java, string, url, inputstream, bufferedreader

I'm trying to read the source code from a browser, but when the code has characters like ã, á, à, õ, I get � instead.

I've tried to apply `java.nio.Charset.encode` on read lines, but no result: the same thing occurs.

My code is:

```
URLConnection connection = ...;
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(connection.getInputStream());
String s = null;

while ((s = reader.readLine()) != null) {
  // got new source line...
}
```

The site I'm trying to read is [this one](http://baixaki.com.br/busca/?q=counter-strike&go=) (PT-BR).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the meta tag, the charset on that page is ISO-8859-1.  Try using:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(connection.getInputStream(), "ISO-8859-1");
```